# Trusted Scripts Setting in Windows Registry or IE

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer, registry

I am creating a directory of files for an internal website. The user will access the page and insert the location and filename and submit the information to a database. I tried using file upload to open Windows Explorer so the user can locate the file and path. However, asp file upload will not allow me to capture the path on the client side. Since this is an internal website, does Internet Explorer or Windows Registry have a permissions setting for trusted scripts similar to trusted sites?

I created a JQuery Script to copy the the path to a textbox but I get a error message saying "C:\fakepath\test.pdf". test.pdf is the filename but c:\fakepath is not the path. I have tried multiple server variables but those just tell the paths on the server end.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
         $("#text1").val($("#text").val());
         });
         });
 </script>
 <input type="file" id="text" />
 <input type="text" id="text1" />
 <input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="button" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the local path you need to use ActiveX object in your web page. It can help you to get the path in IE.

For working with Files and directory you should make a server object as Scripting.FileSystemObject then with GetDirectory() method can get a directory object.

Sample code:

```js
var Fo =new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var StrOut = new String();
var FileName = new String();
var Extention = new String();

function FindFile(FOo)
{
 var FSo = new Enumerator(FOo.Files);
 for(i=0;!FSo.atEnd();FSo.moveNext())
 {
  if(FileName == "*" ||  FSo.item().name.slice(0,FSo.item().name.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase().indexOf(FileName)>-1)
   if(Extention == "*" || FSo.item().name.slice(FSo.item().name.lastIndexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase().indexOf(Extention)>-1){
    StrOut += "<tr "+ ((i%2)? "":"bgcolor=#DDAA55")  +"><td width=50%><font class=find>" + FSo.item().path + "</font></td><td width=25%><font class=find>" + FSo.item().type + "</font></td><td width=50%><font class=find>"+ String(FSo.item().size/(1024*1024)).slice(0,3) +" MB</font></td></tr>";
    i++
    }
 }
}

function Scan()
{
 FileName = (search.value.lastIndexOf(".")>-1)? search.value.slice(0,search.value.lastIndexOf(".")):(search.value.length>0)? search.value.toLowerCase():"*"; //Get Searched File Name
 Extention = (search.value.lastIndexOf(".")>-1)? search.value.slice(search.value.lastIndexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase():"*"; // Get Searched File Extention Name

 if(path.value.length>0 && Fo.FolderExists(path.value)){
  StrOut = "<table border=0 width=100% cellspacing=0>"
  FindFile(Fo.GetFolder(path.value));
  outPut.innerHTML = StrOut+"</table>";
  }
 else alert("Insert Correct Path Address");
}
```

For detailed information and  example code, You can refer link below and download the sample file.

[Find files with JavaScript](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2019/Find-files-with-JavaScript)

Comment: I added more information to my initial question. I am not sure how to solve it using code.

Comment: I am not available with JQuery example but I got the working example in Javascript which you can try to refer in my edited answer. Let me know, If you have any problem to get the file path. I will try to provide further suggestions.